# Does WPF suppress TwoWay binding errors on read-only properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-4.8

Today I rebuilt a WPF application - .NET Framework 4.8 - and our tester came back to me saying that an error was being raised:

> A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property

The error itself is not a problem. I immediately recognised it for what it was, went to the problematic Binding, added `Mode=OneWay` and the problem went away.

### But here's the problem

The original binding was already in the code. Just on a different control. It didn't cause a problem there... but if the property it's binding to is ReadOnly, shouldn't it have caused a problem wherever it's used?

The reason this bothers me so much is that our tester also reported that before the error was raised the application seemed "slow". So it occurred to me that using TwoWay bindings where OneWay bindings should be used, even if WPF is somehow catching and handling the error, is causing a performance impact. If that is the case I need to take action.

### My questions therefore are:

1. Does WPF sometimes handle TwoWay binding errors so that the application continues to work even if the TwoWay binding is inappropriate
2. Can using TwoWay binding inappropriately cause a **significant** performance impact and should I address it?

Comment: A few thoughts I had about this since posting this question. Found a few other sources online (including an 11 year old question on this very site) that indicate that while there is a performance impact it usually isn't so bad that taking action is absolutely necessary. Secondly, I am thinking that perhaps the reason the error was thrown was that something in the application was trying to write data BACK to the bound property, and that caused the error to be raised. i.e. TwoWay binding to a ReadOnly property is not going to cause a problem UNLESS something tries to write to it?

Comment: The default Binding Mode of the property may have changed. Which property did you actually bind?

Comment: Hello @Clemens - I was binding the Text property of a Run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does WPF sometimes handle TwoWay binding errors so that the application continues to work even if the TwoWay binding is inappropriate

It did before .NET Framework 4.5.1. Since this update, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` saying exactly "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property".

> Can using TwoWay binding inappropriately cause a significant performance impact and should I address it?

No. But you should obviously avoid TwoWay bind to read-only properties to avoid getting the exception.

Comment: Yes but we are targeting the .NET Framework 4.8 and have been doing so for ages now. The only thing that changed was that a binding that was originally used in a Tooltip is now being used in the Text property on a Run.

Comment: @Dinah The Run.Text property binds TwoWay by default, while the FrameworkElement.Tooltip property doesn't (because it would be pointless).

Comment: Great. That explains it! Thanks.